# Numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Tags: plsql

```
    create or replace package body M2M_NOTIFICACION is
    
      -- Private type declarations
    
      PROCEDURE M2M_INGRESA_MICROPERSITOR(PN_ID_TICKET   IN NUMBER,
                                          PN_LINEAS      IN NUMBER,
                                          PV_TIPO_TRASAC IN VARCHAR2,
                                          PV_ACCION      IN VARCHAR2,
                                          PV_BP_PLAN     IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                          PV_CUENTA      IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                          PV_USUARIO     IN VARCHAR2,
                                          PN_RUC         IN NUMBER,
                                          PN_COD_ERROR   OUT NUMBER,
                                          PV_MENSAJE     OUT VARCHAR2)
      
       IS
     
      
        selcComando VARCHAR2(4096);
        instComando VARCHAR2(100);
        lcComando   VARCHAR2(4096);
        LV_MESAJE   VARCHAR2(20);
        LV_CODERROR VARCHAR2(5);
        LBUSCARDATO NUMBER;
      
      BEGIN
      
        lcComando := 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMPORAL_MICRO (ID_TICKET NUMBER,
                                 LINEAS NUMBER,
                                 TIPO_TRASAC VARCHAR2(100),
                                 ACCION   VARCHAR2(100),
                                 BP_PLAN   VARCHAR2(100),
                                 CUENTA    VARCHAR2(100),
                                 USUARIO   VARCHAR2(100),
                                 RUC       INT)ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS';
      
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lcComando;
      
        ***instComando := 'INSERT INTO TEMPORAL_A(ID_TICKET, LINEAS, TIPO_TRASAC, ACCION, BP_PLAN, CUENTA, USUARIO, RUC)
        VALUES
          (PN_ID_TICKET,
           PV_LINEAS,
           PV_TIPO_TRASAC,
           PV_ACCION,
           PV_BP_PLAN,
           PV_CUENTA,
           PV_USUARIO,
           PV_RUC)';
      
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE instComando;***
      
        selcComando := 'SELECT ID_TICKET
          INTO LBUSCARDATO
          FROM TEMPORAL_A
         WHERE ID_TICKET = PN_ID_TICKET
           AND LINEAS = PV_LINEAS
           AND TIPO_TRASAC = PV_TIPO_TRASAC
           AND ACCION = PV_ACCION
           AND BP_PLAN = PV_BP_PLAN
           AND CUENTA = PV_CUENTA
           AND USUARIO = PV_USUARIO
           AND RUC = PV_RUC;';
      
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE selcComando;
      
        IF LBUSCARDATO = PN_ID_TICKET THEN
          LV_MESAJE  := 'TABLA Y DATO INGRESADO';
          PV_MENSAJE := LV_MESAJE;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(PV_MENSAJE);
        ELSE
          LV_CODERROR  := '00000';
          LV_MESAJE    := 'INFORMACION NO INSERTADA';
          PN_COD_ERROR := LV_CODERROR;
          PV_MENSAJE   := LV_MESAJE;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LV_CODERROR || '-' || LV_MESAJE);
        END IF; 
      END M2M_INGRESA_MICROPERSITOR;
    
    end M2M_NOTIFICACION;
```

Tengo problemas con mi procedimiento. Quiero crear una tabla temporal e insertar valores que recibo con el procedimiento pero me marca este error:

```
    ERROR NUMERYC OR VALUE ERROR: CHARACTER STRING BUFFER TOO SMALL
```

Comment: Bienvenido, cual es el error que se muestra, agrega más información, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: NO ES NECESARIO QUE GRITES EN EL TÍTULO. En su lugar, pulsa en [edit] y pon un título descriptivo: lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Saludos, tienes variables VARCHAR2 declaradas con un tamaño demasiado pequeño para la cantidad de caracteres que le estás asignando, por ello el error "CHARACTER STRING BUFFER TOO SMALL", por ejemplo:

instComando

```
      está declarado como Varchar2(100), 
      pero recibe más de 100 caracteres con la sentencia 'insert...'
```

LV_MESAJE

```
      está declarada con máximo 20 caracteres,
      pero el texto asignado tiene 24 caracteres: 'INFORMACION NO INSERTADA'
```

Sugerencia: Se soluciona aumentando el número de precisión en la declaración de las variables. Ejemplo:

instComando varchar2(500);
LV_MESAJE   varchar2(60);

Espero te sea de ayuda.